# why does Visual Studio modify "Windows Form Designer generated code" on designer open?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

When working w/ a WinForm project in VS.NET 2015, our team has noticed that the mere act of opening a .VB form in the designer view (default action when double-clicking the file in Solution Explorer) will cause VS to modify many object properties in the "Windows Form Designer generated code" section of the actual .VB code-behind. It seems to be limited to the .Size and .Location properties for sometimes dozens or more of UI objects, always changing their X,Y coords just slightly.

Mind you we don't perform any action to drive this -- simply open the file (obtained from source-control and residing in the local solution/project) in VS.NET's form designer by double-clicking the file in Solution Explorer, and bam -- it has the "unsaved" asterisk and if you save it and compare to source control version you can see the modifications already made.

I couldn't find much on this. Is this a known behavior? Any idea why it does this? Kind of reminds me of the old days w/ MS FrontPage's designer view, and even the early days of ASP.NET in VS which would apply some HTML changes if you opened a WebForm in designer view, until they gave the option to disable that on a later release.

thanks for any input.

**UPDATE**: this appears to be continuing even with myself as the only editor of the .VB form in designer. various form elements are shifting their position very slightly. Here's a diff screenshot between my last check in and today, and I know I'm the only one editing:

[image]

...there are many like that. Always these two properties, always just a few pixels difference.

Comment: Does this happen with every form or with just a particular form with some specific controls on it (TabControl for example)

Comment: great question. I'm not certain of the others, but yes this form does have a TabControl

Comment: I can't answer to this question, but could it be possible that this happens because VS remakes all design calculation and scaling when form is shown, considering Font and Screen configurations that are particular to some environment? Is the solution in a network folder to be open in more than one computer (even if not simultaneously)? Is Form's `Autoscale` property set to Font or other instead of `None`?

Comment: I used to have this problem constantly on any form that contained one of DevExpress' Layout controls.

Comment: not on a network share but is in a code repository that's downloaded locally, worked on by multiple people with similar workstations, and checked back in. I didnt know VS calculates that when form is shown. I didn't find an `Autoscale` property but did find `AutoScaleBaseSize` set to a size and `AutoScaleMode` is set to `Inherit`. `AutoSize` is set to `False` and `AutoSizeMode` is set to `GrowOnly`.

Comment: You probably have developers whose screens use different DPIs, so the designer recalculates the form's layout each time it is displayed. There is no good solution to this. You either have to standardize all of your development environments at 96 DPI, or eschew using the designer.

Comment: dont know for sure but that sounds plausible - two devs are on 120, one is 96. it does seem like the majority of the changes were from the 120 dev machines opening a version last edited by the 96.

Comment: I've experienced the same and I'm just a sole developer on one machine. Seems totally random to me. In fact, there's a solution right now that everytime I go open it it wants to save a form if I immediately close it. However, it hasn't always done that. Just since about my last checkin I'd guess.

Comment: Maybe on this form maybe you set programmatically the location and/or the size of some controls based on form size or something else dependency. So when you display the form it needs to calculate this.

Comment: I have also begun having this problem, but with only 1 form in my project. Also, pre-"Designer Generated Code"-changes code and post-changes code are identical (no shifting locations).  I have absolutely nothing fancy in my setup: 1 developer, 1 machine, all files saved in VS default local disk location, no addins or 3rd party anything of any kind, basic forms with simple controls and buttons, same monitor/resolution/etc as always and is identical to my second monitor. Very weird and very annoying

Answer (score 3):

I don't have an specific answer for this, but since this drove us crazy a bit a few months ago with my team, while working on a WinForms project, I am glad to share my experience!

Every time someone opened any form on VS2015, it would ask other people who has the same solution open at that time to reload the code. We first thought the third party controls (at that time it was both DevExpress and Infragistics) we are using were re-generated on designed initialization - because they tend to do that a lot but then we realised this kept happening on forms that only contains .NET controls.

Now the funny part. This only happened to us on VS2015. We were using VS2013 before, without this annoying problem.

Long story short, then we realized the screens we are using have different DPIs, just like Cody Gray said. I am not absolutely sure if this was the reason, but since we started using TFS, obviously we don't have the problem anymore... Hope this helps somehow lol.